# JQuery Ajax: Posting XML onto PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I am trying to post an XML message on a PHP server from an external provider.

I am using the following Javascript code to try and do so:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    },
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'xml',
    async: false,

    complete: function (result) {
        console.log(response.status);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, tranStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(
            'Status: ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText + '. ' +
            'Response: ' + jqXHR.responseText
        );
    }
```

But I always get the error

**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

I thought I could sole it by enabling crossDomain but it didn't.

Comment: `dataType: 'xml'` - Guess this is only for the receiving end. Not for sending. For sending you need to use `headers: {}` object.

Comment: You need to enable CORS on the server by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Comment: Let us assume that the server provider is not cooperative on that matter, so adjusting the server is out of the question. :(

Comment: The other option is to create proxy script in php that will read the page and return the response.